# Website is resolving to localhost?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, dns, localhost, traceroute

For some reason, the website [funshion.com](http://www.funshion.com/?ta=1) resolves to `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) when I run it on `tracert`. The website should, of course, go to the website, not to my computer.

Basically, Funshion is a program used to watch Asian television shows. I installed it a few years ago in Windows XP. It worked fine, up until a few days ago, when the app started returning errors. I couldn't figure out why it stopped working, and I still don't know. So, I uninstalled it. However, when I tried to reinstall it, the website wouldn't load. So I finally tried running `tracert` on the URL, and then realized it leads to `localhost`, for some reason.

I first checked the `hosts` file but there was nothing there that could be causing the problem, and the file itself hadn't been edited in two years. Where else can I check to see why this particular URL resolves to `localhost`?

In addition, if I use my iPod Touch and connect to the same WiFi network that this computer is connected to, I can visit the website just fine, so the problem is not the network; it's the computer.

As a side note, every once in a while, the website will load the text and CSS, just not the images. I'm guessing that these might be cached, though, although I'm not entirely sure as I've already cleared the cache a few times, even after all of these problems started to occur.

Here's the full `tracert` output:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\user>tracert funshion.com

Tracing route to funshion.com [127.0.0.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  localhost [127.0.0.1]

Trace complete.

C:\Documents and Settings\user>
```

---

Okay so I ran `ipconfig /displaydns`. Funsion was there (as seen in the following piece of code). For some reason, it keeps coming back even if I run `ipconfig /flushdns`. I think it's re-added if I try visiting the Funshion website in Firefox, for some reason. How can I find out where this is coming from so I can remove it permanently? (And, as I said earlier, it's not the `hosts` file; I DO have entries in that file and they do indeed appear in `displaydns`, but they don't disappear for a second—they always appear in `displaydns`).

```
www.funshion.com
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : www.funshion.com
Record Type . . . . . : 1
Time To Live  . . . . : 19573
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Answer
A (Host) Record . . . : 127.0.0.1


Record Name . . . . . : ns2.ai-dns.com
Record Type . . . . . : 1
Time To Live  . . . . : 19573
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Additional
A (Host) Record . . . : 173.224.216.142


Record Name . . . . . : ns4.ai-dns.com
Record Type . . . . . : 1
Time To Live  . . . . : 19573
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Additional
A (Host) Record . . . : 173.224.216.142


Record Name . . . . . : ns1.ai-dns.com
Record Type . . . . . : 1
Time To Live  . . . . : 19573
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Additional
A (Host) Record . . . : 116.255.158.133


Record Name . . . . . : ns3.ai-dns.com
Record Type . . . . . : 1
Time To Live  . . . . : 19573
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Additional
A (Host) Record . . . : 180.186.11.138
```

Comment: You need to troubleshoot. What nameserver are you using? What does `nslookup` return?

Comment: @Ramhound: That would have been my first suggestion as well, but looks like he already did that.

Comment: Okay so I added some more information to my post. I narrowed down the problem; for some reason Funshion keeps adding to my DNS even after I flush it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so ultimately what I did was I changed the computer's DNS from the default ISP ones to Google's public DNS. That seems to have fixed it. I still don't exactly know why the DNS record for Funshion keeps adding itself, but now it seems to have stopped doing that after I changed DNS.